# ArcGIS Server Javascript Reporting

Tags: javascript, report, reporting, arcgis

I am just wondering if ArcGIS Javascript has ability to create tabular report, similar with Crystal Report. Can we make some kind of report template and publish it? I think we can create this kind of report with ArcMAP, but I don't know if I work with ArcGIS Server for Javascript.

What I am going to do is create a report, insert graphs, export the report (maybe to PDF), and print report. All done on web based ArcGIS for javascript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into these sample code examples. They introduce you to a good deal of the api available in ArcGIS javascript for printing  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_print.html